# useState always is default value in itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using `useState` to manage the **state**, it's working fine. But when i return state inside itseft, it always value of initial

```
import react, {useState} from 'react'

const MyComponent = () => {
    const [myState, setMyState] = useState({
        value: 'initial value',
        setValue: (newValue) => {
            setMyState({...myState, value: newValue})
            console.log(myState.value) //<--always is 'initial value'
        }
    })

    return(
        <>
            <p>{myState.value}</p> //<-- it's working fine
            <input value={myState.value} onChange={(e) => myState.setValue(e.target.value)} /> //<--working fine too

        </>
    )
}
```

I expect the `console.log` is value of input, but the actual output always is initial value

Comment: That code won't parse, which makes it hard to understand what you're really doing and help you understand whatever the problem is. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). (To use hooks, you'll need to follow the instructions there for using a more recent version than in the drop-down list.)

Comment: The only parameter that `useState` takes is the initial state. It seems to me you are expecting it to take some kind of configuration object. Where have you found that? The correct line is more like: `const [myState, setState] = useState('initial value')` and that's it.

Comment: May I ask you from where you got the syntax for usestate()?

Comment: For some reason, i wanna define the function inside MyState.

Comment: @mikenlanggio "For some reason" isn't useful. We need to know **why** in order to help you. (Helping you in this case almost certainly involves explaining what to do instead of defining your function inside MyState.)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
const [myState, setMyState] = useState({
    value: 'initial value',
    setValue: (newValue) => {
        setMyState({...myState, value: newValue})
        console.log(myState.value) //<--always is 'initial value'
    }
})
```

The first time your component function is run, the `setValue` function captures the *initial* value of `myState`. The second time it is run, you make a copy of the `setValue` function—but this is the function that has has captured the *initial* value of `myState`. It never updates.

Since the function never changes, you should not put it in `useState()` in the first place. You can define the function separately.

```
const [myState, setMyState] = useState({ value: 'initial value' })
const setValue = (newValue) => {
  setMyState({ ...myState, value: newValue })
}
```

Now, a new `setValue` copy is created every time the component function is run. When capturing variables, you can use [`useCallback()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) for optimization; if the values didn't change, React will reuse old copies of the function.

```
const [myState, setMyState] = useState({ value: 'initial value' })
const setValue = useCallback((newValue) => {
  setMyState({ ...myState, value: newValue })
}, [myState]) // ← this bit ensures that the value is always up to date inside the callback
```

As mentioned by Shubham Khatri, there is an even faster and better approach in this situation: using the [functional form of `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).

```
const [myState, setMyState] = useState({ value: 'initial value' })
const setValue = useCallback((newValue) => {
  setMyState((prev) => ({ ...prev, value: newValue }))
}, []) // ← now we use an empty array, so React will never update this callback
```

Any of these three methods are fine to use, though; they will all work and perform good enough for most use cases.

---

Per comments, you're attempting to create an object that is passed down via context. A way to do this is by creating the context object in a separate step, similarly to how we created the callback function. This time, we use [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo), which is similar to `useCallback` but works for any type of object.

```
// Per T.J. Crowder's answer, you can use separate `useState` calls if you need multiple values.
const [myState, setMyState] = useState('initial value')
const ctx = useMemo(() => ({
  value: myState,
  setValue: (newValue) => {
    setMyState(newValue)
  }
}), [myState])

return (
  <Provider value={ctx}>
    {children}
  </Provider>
)
```

Comment: I know it! But, for some reason, i wanna define the function inside MyState.

Comment: What is the reason? You most likely have to do something different.

Comment: But, inside `p` and `input`. It's still working fine. Right?.

Comment: Yup. I used it like a provider of useContext. I wanna change the state itself inside child Component

Comment: Why even pass an object to `useState`? Just pass the string itself and the function returned by `useState` will even update it like you want it without having to provide a custom handler.

Comment: No. I just pass MyState. And inside child Component, i can change MyState by call function inside the state

Answer (score 6):

[goto-bus-stop's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56109186/157247) explains why you're getting the problem you're getting. But there's another thing to address here:

From the code you've provided, it looks like you're using an object as your state value. In particular, this line:

```
setMyState({...myState, value: newValue})
```

..suggests you intend `myState` to have multiple things in it, with `value` just being one of them.

That's not how you do it with hooks. It's fine to have an object as a state value, but generally you do that when you're going to update (that is, replace) the *entire* object when the state changes. If you're updating individual parts of the state (as suggested by the above), you use individual `useState` calls instead of an object. See comments:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const MyComponent = () => {
    // Separate `useState` calls for each state item
    const [value, setValue] = useState('initial value');
    const [anotherValue, setAnotherValue] = useState('another value');

    // No need to create your own update function, that's what `setValue` and
    // `setAnotherValue` are, just use them:

    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <p>{value}</p>
            <input value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
            <p>{anotherValue}</p>
            <input value={anotherValue} onChange={(e) => setAnotherValue(e.target.value)} />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

This separation is particularly useful if you have any side effects of state changes, because you can specify what state triggers the side effect. For instance, here's the component above which triggers a `console.log` when `value` changes but not when `anotherValue` changes, and another effect that occurs when *either* of them changes:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const MyComponent = () => {
    // Separate `useState` calls for each state item
    const [value, setValue] = useState('initial value');
    const [anotherValue, setAnotherValue] = useState('another value');
    // A counter for all changes; we use -1 because
    // our effect runs on initial mount
    const [changes, setChanges] = useState(-1);

    // No need to create your own update function, that's what `setValue` and
    // `setAnotherValue` are, just use them:
  
    // A side-effect for when `value` changes:
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`value changed to ${value}`);
    }, [value]); // <=== Notice that we declare what triggers this effect

    // A side-effect for when *either* `value` or `anotherValue` changes:
    useEffect(() => {
        setChanges(changes + 1);
    }, [value, anotherValue]);

    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <p>Total changes: {changes}</p>
            <p>{value}</p>
            <input value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
            <p>{anotherValue}</p>
            <input value={anotherValue} onChange={(e) => setAnotherValue(e.target.value)} />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the function inside the useState argument isn't aware of the update since its only called once and has the value from its closure. Secondly the way you are using useState is not correct, you must instead only have the value in useState and have the handlers outside

Also you must use callback pattern

```
import react, {useState} from 'react'

const MyComponent = () => {
    const [myState, setMyState] = useState('initial value');   
    const setValue = (newValue) => {
         setMyState(newValue)
    }
    console.log(myState);
    return(
        <>
            <p>{myState}</p> 
            <input value={myState} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />

        </>
    )
}
```

Also state update is asynchronous so the update is not reflected immediately instead after the next render

Comment: prev is working, but how can i console current myState without call setMyState?

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this will be

```
import react, {useState} from 'react'

const MyComponent = () => {
    const [ value, setValue ] = useState('initial value');
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setValue(e.target.value);
    }

    return(
        <>
            <p>{myState}</p>
            <input value={myState.value} onChange={handleChange} />
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: I know it. But, for some reason, i have to define the function inside MyState.

Comment: Not recommended. state is usually for variables and not functions